# Not able to Convert float to Char in C#

Tags: c#

Why this code won't compile without throwing an exception???
**I am trying to convert float test to a character from ASCII table.**

```
float test = 42.5F;
char convertFloatToChar = Convert.ToChar(test);
Console.WriteLine(convertFloatToChar);
```

Comment: What `char` your expect it should return?

Comment: What result are you expecting? What conversion makes sense to you, logically? Because there are few that make sense to me. Are you perhaps thinking that `char` is a numeric type, like in C? For that, use `short`/`byte`

Comment: I think what you want is String. try string convertFloatToString = Convert.ToString(test);

Answer (score 1):

If you check the overload for [Convert.ToChar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tochar(v=vs.110).aspx) then you will see that the exception is logical. You cannot have a float/double in Convert.ToChar() method.

> **ToChar(Double)**
>
> Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

You are probably looking for

```
float test = 42.5F;
String convertFloatToChar = Convert.ToString(test);
Console.WriteLine(convertFloatToChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a string:

```
float test = 42.5F;
String convertFloatToString = Convert.ToString(test);
Console.WriteLine(convertFloatToString);
```